# Trigger Scheduled Events from Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

**Scenario**

I am making a small Web application based on Yii2.

There are 2 entities 'User' and 'Admin' in my system.

**Required solution for:**

I want to know if there is any facility in Yii2 where I can trigger Scheduled Events like *creating User Registration expiry*, *promotional emails and stuff* ?

Currently I am triggering event when Admin logs in, but I want this Scheduled irrespective of whether Admin logs in or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an action in console controller which will handle events and execute it regularly using CRON.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Could provide and Web Resource/ Web Link for the explanation you provided me?

Comment: Thanks, I found it out this with your help : https://youtu.be/EZhYp6cPD5E